Javascript can't/won't update items in a sidebar
I'm using FastAPI and some basic HTML/CSS.   I use javascript to change text, images, colors on the front end based on what the backend does.
One are I am fighting with is updating an image in a navigation side bar.  If I put this same image in the main window with a different ID I can verify the update works.  But it won't work in a sidebar and I don't know why.


var CD = document.getElementById("compact_disk");
rotate = `rotate(90deg)`
CD.style.transform = rotate;
/* The sidebar menu */
.sidenav {
   height: 100%; /* Full-height: remove this if you want "auto" height */
   width: 160px; /* Set the width of the sidebar */
   position: fixed; /* Fixed Sidebar (stay in place on scroll) */
   z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
   top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
   left: 0;
   background-color: #111; /* Black */
   overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
   padding-top: 20px;
}
<!-- Side navigation -->
<div class="sidenav" id="sidebar">
  <div class="image-container">
     <a href="/page/media"><img id="compact_disk" 
        width=24 height=24 src="/images/compact_disk.png"
        class="white-svg"/>Media</a>
  </div>
</div>



The code runs, without errors. But also without rotating the image.
If I console.log(CD), in my browser debug window I can see the change.
If I hover it (using Firefox) it highlight the elements and I can see the debug box is rotated 90 degrees, but the image itself not.
If I place a similar image outside of the nav bar and update it, no problem.

When does that JavaScript run? How is it triggered? Where in your code is it inserted?

Your code works for me.

I'm running the code on during onmessage() function. But for this example I just put it in $(document).ready(function (). I'm checking your second comment now. Thanks

Thank you!  I took a bunch of my code and dumped it in there and saw the navigation bar duplicated.  Apparently there were two includes in the template!
